# How send POST in JIRA C# return statusCode 400

Tags: c#

I try to send data with POST method to JIRA, but I get Error 400 in the UploadString () method.

The token is correct and the Json and tested in POSTMAN is OK, which is the problem?

I've been with this for several days and I can not solve it, could someone be kind enough to help me? Thank you

```
string json = @"{
                     'fields': {
                            'project': {
                                'key': 'EXAMPLE',
                                'projectTypeKey': 'service_exam'
                            },
                            'customfield_11283': {
                                'self': 'https://example.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14538',
                                'value': 'HELLO',
                                'id': '14538'
                            },
                            'issuetype': {
                                'self': 'https://example.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/11835',
                                'id': '11835',
                                'description': '',
                                'name': 'EXTac',
                                'subtask': false
                            },
                            'summary': '-',
                            'customfield_10300': {
                                                'requestType': {
                                                    '_expands': [
                                                        'field'
                                                    ],
                                                    'id': '119',
                                                    '_links': {
                                                        'self': 'https://example.atlassian.net/rest/serviceexmapi/serviceexm/11/requesttype/119'
                                                    },
                                                    'name': 'ExmTick 40517',
                                                    'description': 'Register Peter Parker',
                                                    'helpText': '
                                                    'issueTypeId':'10835', 

                                                    'groupIds': [ '24' ]
                                                 }
                                            } 
                                }
                        }";
```

And mi code with the credentials in ATLASSIAN JIRA and the request is:

```
string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
    var userid = "user@example.com";
    var password = "QLodasdTCdt7Exampledsfsdf";
    var endpoint = "https://example.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue?";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Basic " + GetEncodedCredentials(userid, password));
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var uri = new Uri(endpoint);
            var response = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", json);
            jsonResponse = response;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                HttpWebResponse wrsp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                var statusCode = (int)wrsp.StatusCode;
                var msg = wrsp.StatusDescription;
                throw new HttpException(statusCode, msg);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

And the method for convert in UTF8 is:

```
private static string GetEncodedCredentials(string userid, string password)
    {
        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userid, password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
    }
```

Comment: what response do you get back? Could you please add the full response here?

Comment: The code breaks in the line var response = client.UploadString (uri, "POST", json); I do not know what response returns, I only see that the error is 400

Comment: You could inspect the response in fiddler and post it here maybe? Also is there a reason that you’re using WebClient over HttpClient?

Comment: Telerik Fiddler no show connection, ( setting with HTTPS )

Comment: are you actually hitting 'https://example.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue?' end-point, or is this just a dummy end-point?

Comment: No is real, is a example.